# Check for duplicated attribute data in sibling elements - Schematron

Tags: validation, xpath, schematron

I'm trying to write a check in Schematron that will ensure no  elements contain duplicated attribute data. These  elements are at a specific location in the XML document, I have the XPATH that locates them.

For example:

should fail because it has duplicate foo and bar attribute values.

```
<id foo="test1" bar="abc" />
<id foo="test1" bar="abc" />
```

This should pass as the foo attributes are not the same.

```
<id foo="test1" bar="abc" /> 
<id foo="test2" bar="abc" />
```

I'm not sure if this is too complicated for Schematron.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Schematron, but if you're able to use XPath 2.0 (which is possible [at least with some implementations](http://www.xfront.com/schematron/schematron-and-xpath2.html)), [`deep-equal($val1, $val2)`](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_deep-equal.html) will come in handy.

```
not(deep-equal(<id foo="test1" bar="abc" />, <id foo="test1" bar="abc" />)) (: false :)
not(deep-equal(<id foo="test1" bar="abc" />, <id foo="test2" bar="abc" />)) (: true :)
```

If not, there should be a solution using XSLT 1.0, but you will have to construct the recursive comparisons on your own (and I don't know XSLT well enough to do so).

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way in Schematron (checked with XML ValidatorBuddy):

```
<iso:pattern id="unique name attributes">
  <iso:rule context="id">
    <iso:assert test="count(id) = count(id[not(@foo=preceding-sibling::person/@foo)])">
     Not all foo attributes of the id elements are unique
    </iso:assert>
 </iso:rule>
</iso:pattern>
```

You can also add a check for the bar attribute here.