# Check for duplicated data with multiple attribute in sibling elements - Schematron

Tags: xml, validation, schematron

As described in the title, I want to find a way to check duplicated attribute data in XML sibling elements.

I already know the similar question 
[here] [Check for duplicated attribute data in sibling elements - Schematron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618276/check-for-duplicated-attribute-data-in-sibling-elements-schematron) ,and i've tried through it, not worked for me.

My situation is to check with multiple attributes.

```
<root>
  <test ZDX="a" XH="1" ps="sdf"/>
  <test ZDX="a" XH="2" ps="dfg"/>
  <test ZDX="a" XH="3" ps="hfgh"/>
  <test ZDX="a" XH="2" ps="ertewr"/><!--same with the 2nd line-->
</root>
```

I need the `<test>` element to be unique with `ZDX` and `XH` attribute.
all the sibling element of test should satisfy that both `ZDX` and `XH` attribute can't be equal to another test at the same time, or then the SchemaTron validate error is fired.

i have tried this way,

```
<rule context="/root/test">
  <assert test="count(self::test) = count(self::test[not(@ZDX=preceding-sibling::test/@ZDX and @XH=preceding-sibling::test/@XH)])">
  test is not unique
  </assert>
</rule>
```

it works fine with the situation above ,but not work for situation below

```
<root>
  <test ZDX="a" XH="1" ps="sdf"/>
  <test ZDX="a" XH="2" ps="dfg"/>
  <test ZDX="a" XH="3" ps="hfgh"/>
  <test ZDX="a" XH="4" ps="ertewr"/>
  <test ZDX="b" XH="5" ps="ndmfj"/>
  <test ZDX="b" XH="6" ps="yuoi"/>
  <test ZDX="b" XH="4" ps="qwrew"/><!--conflict with the 4th line-->
</root>
```

in the last `test` element, the `XH="4"` will fire the validation, if i change the last line 
`<test ZDX="b" XH="4" ps="qwrew"/>`to `<test ZDX="b" XH="7" ps="qwrew"/>`，it turns to be unique,and won't fire the validation.

so,how can i check with both `ZDX` and `XH` in one Schematron Test phrase?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
<sch:pattern id="duplicate-attribute" abstract="true">
    <sch:rule context="$element">
        <sch:report test="@$attribute = following-sibling::$element/@$attribute 
            or @$attribute = preceding-sibling::$element/@$attribute">
            Duplicate '$attribute' attribute value found
        </sch:report>
    </sch:rule>
</sch:pattern>

<sch:pattern is-a="duplicate-attribute">
    <sch:param name="element" value="test"/>
    <sch:param name="attribute" value="XH"/>
</sch:pattern>

<sch:pattern is-a="duplicate-attribute">
    <sch:param name="element" value="test"/>
    <sch:param name="attribute" value="ZDX"/>
</sch:pattern>
```